# Error installing Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle 11gR2 on my ubuntu machine. I tried this tutorial [Install Oracle Database 11gR2 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2461988?start=0&tstart=0)

when I start the installer by running `./runInstaller` I am getting this error

```
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

    Checking Temp space: must be greater than 80 MB.   Actual 307621 MB    Passed
    Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 47682 MB    Passed
    Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
        >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n] y


>>> Ignoring required pre-requisite failures. Continuing...

Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from 



      /tmp/OraInstall2015-06-08_11-46-03AM. Please wait ...oracle@Linux-14:~/database$ No protocol specified



    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:821)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:804)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(Unknown Source)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:122)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1783)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:480)
        at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:758)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
        at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
        at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:114)
        at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:132)
```

Can anyone help me in this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on a server without x server? The installer tries to initialize a SWT Window for a GUI.

Try running the install command with `./runInstaller -mode=console`, maybe this will help - some oracle installers have this option, hopefully this one as well.

Comment: NO I am not running any kind of server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install express edition:
http://www.varyonic.com/2010/01/installing-oracle-xe-on-ubuntu/#.VYMvB9Slyko